# Dialog max width after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

I need to support both landscape and portrait screen sizes and want my Dialog to fit the whole available width. This doesn't happen if I use default settings (Dialog's width is same in landscape and portrait rotations). I also need to dismiss the dialog clicking left or right from it (there should be enough space by design). How can I reach it?

I tried to set `usePlatformDefaultWidth = true` and make custom free space inside the dialog but this space is not reconsidered as a dismissible area. Also `Dialog` has no `Modifier` parameter that could solve this problem easily.

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { viewModel.showDialog(null) },
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = true),
) {
    Surface(Modifier.padding(32.dp).wrapContentSize()) {
        //...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, and you want to set the maximum width of the `Dialog`, you can try the following code:

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { viewModel.showDialog(null) },
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you want the `Dialog` to be as wide as possible but still have some horizontal padding, so that when you click on the free space between the `Dialog` and the edge of the screen, `onDismissRequest` is called, you can try the following code:

```
Dialog(
onDismissRequest = { viewModel.showDialog(null) },
properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
) {
    val horizontalPadding = 48.dp
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(max = (LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp - (horizontalPadding * 2)))
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Update:
Changed `.width` to `.widthIn(max=...)` to set max allowed width with padding

Comment: It looks like padding is not working to provide the free space in my case.

Comment: The problem with this solution: the dialog expands above the content's width.

Comment: Can you attach an image to your question of what `Dialog` behavior you expect?

Comment: This is correct behavior you provided but you missed the case when the content width is much smaller than the `screenWidthDp - (horizontalPadding * 2)`.

Comment: @Psijic, check out the updated solution

Comment: This is fine. Looks like `widthIn` is something relatively new or rarely used.

Comment: This is generally used if you need to set either the minimum allowed value or the maximum allowed value. Did this answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes. `.wrapContentHeight()` is unnecessary here.